# Not able to run selenium script using phantomjs driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, phantomjs

I am new to phantomjs driver, I need to run my script in background using phantomjs headless driver.
Here is my code i am getting null-pointer exception.
currently am using selenium 2.32,testNG,phantomjs jar 1.0.3

```
public class PhantomjsDemo {

public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,"C:\\phantomjs-1.9.2-windows\\phantomjs.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
     driver.get("www.google.com");
}

@Test
public void google(){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfba']")).getText();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfba']")).getSize().getHeight();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfba']")).getSize().getWidth();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='gbqfba']")).click();
}

@AfterMethod
public void close(){
    driver.quit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing your `Webdriver` member variable in the setup() method, but a method variable:

```
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Change it to

```
this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

and the NPE should go away.

Comment: I changed to this.driver = new phantomJSDriver Still am getting this error.[ERROR - 2013-10-03T13:12:16.852Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1380805936812
[INFO  - 2013-10-03T13:12:17.032Z] ShutdownReqHand - _handle - About to shutdown
FAILED: google
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:

Comment: Now thats another problem and question then, I never worked with PhantomJS. The xpath looks OK, though I probably would use `//button[@id='gbqfba']`. Check if the right HTML document is loaded, maybe there is a problem (maybe use `http://`www.google.de).